# How to search and remove a string using regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:

```
'<div class="hotels-hotel-review-about-with-photos-Reviews__subratingRow--2u0CJ"><span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_45"></span><div class="hotels-hotel-review-about-with-photos-Reviews__subratingLabel--H8ZI0">Location</div></div>'
```

and I want to extract the numeric value that comes after `bubble_`, which is `45`.

I have tried:

```
rating = re.search('bubble_(\d+)', str(line)).group(0)
rating = re.sub("bubble_" , '', rating)
```

My code works, but I was wondering if there is a more pythonic was to do this. (Instead of two lines of code, only one line!)
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
(?<=bubble_)(\d+)
```

And use one line:

```
rating = re.search('(?<=bubble_)(\d+)', str(line)).group(0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just replace `.group(0)` with `.group(1)` to access the contents of the capture group:

```
line = '<div class="hotels-hotel-review-about-with-photos-Reviews__subratingRow--2u0CJ"><span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_45"></span><div class="hotels-hotel-review-about-with-photos-Reviews__subratingLabel--H8ZI0">Location</div></div>'
rating = re.search('bubble_(\d+)', str(line)).group(1)
print rating
```

Output:

```
45
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
rating = re.sub("bubble_" , '', re.search('bubble_(\d+)', str(line)).group(0))
```

Honestly I would prefer writing this in 2 lines to improve readability.

Comment: this works, but is there a way to use one command instead of two?

Comment: In my solution and yours, two commands have been used" ```re.sub``` and ```re.search```. Is there a way to use only one command? probably using a better regex?

Comment: @Pie-ton does Sergio's answer work?  There probably is a way, but I am not very good with regex.